# Definition Files; Which version Fits my Package(s)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

To keep this short, how do I determine which type definitions to use with a specific version of an NPM Package.  I have read through the typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html) and not been able to figure this out.

React for example, at the time of writing is currently at version 16.4.1; and @types/react is currently at version 16.4.7; is there an official database or official documentation on which @types/react version is married to react@15.6.1 (For example).

I want to assume that the @types version number correlates to the matching version of the NPM package (i.e. @types/react@16.4.7 correlates to react@16.4.7) but that does not appear to be the case.

If this question has already been asked/answered, please link to it and I'll mark that as the answer as well as update this question with the details for future googlers.